# Excel 2016 Data Validation drop down menu performance

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2016

I have a relatively large Excel workbook, and in one sheet I have to use data validation (list) on two of the columns. I would prefer to use the drop down box but for some reasons the performance is horrid, it takes multiple seconds to navigate between cells. However, if I use the same data validation but without the dropdown box arrow it's back to being snappy and quick.

I've tried googleing and searching here to no avail. In excel I have tried turning on and off the following to no help:

- Hardware acceleration of graphics
- Multi-threaded calculation
- Multi-threaded processing
- Recalculation of formulas

Computer is a Zbook 15 with i7-6700HQ and Nvidia Quadro M1000M.
Any hints or help is greatly appreciated.

[Image showing slow response when moving over data validation cells. Arrow keys beeing clicked at same pace all the time.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KWi62.gif)

Comment: It's very unusual activity,, possible reasons are Drop down has a longer list,,, Slowness of Processor,,, better post the GIF of the Sheet so readers may observe the issue!!

Comment: Edited to include image.

Comment: nothing unusual I've found it's normal speed to move cursor while pressing Up/Down key !!

Comment: Does the issue only occur with the  large Excel workbook? Based on my tests with Excel for Office 365, I didn't reproduce the issue in a new blank workbook and some  existing workbooks.If you put it into Manual calculation mode, will navigating between cells be faster?